# Using mathpazo only for small caps?

Tags: small-caps

Really simple question...

```
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo} <-- How can I make it alter only small caps?
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider using `newpx`, a palatino-clone based on `TeX-Gyre-Pagella`, which has true small caps in roman, italic, bold and bold-italic.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}

Text \textit{text \textbf{text}} \textbf{text}

\end{document}
```

After compiling, I ran `pdffonts`, getting this output

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DTGJVU+URWPalladioL-Roma             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
LAWSFM+URWPalladioL-Ital             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
DCSYXP+URWPalladioL-BoldItal         Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
RLNCFA+URWPalladioL-Bold             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       7  0
```

The same example file with `mathpazo`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

Text \textit{text \textbf{text}} \textbf{text}

\end{document}
```

and the output of `pdffonts` is

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DTGJVU+URWPalladioL-Roma             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
LAWSFM+URWPalladioL-Ital             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
DCSYXP+URWPalladioL-BoldItal         Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
RLNCFA+URWPalladioL-Bold             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       7  0
```

As you can clearly see, the fonts are *exactly* the same.

So just replace

```
\usepackage{palatino}
```

with

```
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
```

---

If, for some reason, you don't trust the above, use `substitutefont`:

```
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{\encodingdefault}{\scdefault}{pplx}
```

On the other hand, the documentation of `psnfss` has

[image]

The part about `mathpazo` also tells you why you should prefer it to `palatino`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to add new font family (`pplx`) to the `\scshape` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{palatino}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\scshape}{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont}{}{}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\scshape\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare to the output without this patch:

[image]